# Trying to lookup word or expression てんとてん

Tags: words, definitions

I can remember hearing this combination of sounds several times, and the way it's used makes me think that it's a part of a common phase or saying.  Particularly I can point to two cases where it was used in Ergo Proxy episode 1.  In one case, it had the following usage, with the meaning that two events that were just mentioned are probably connected.

> てんとてん　は　せい　に　なる

I'm not writing that with any kanji because this was just heard, and I can't claim to know any of the meanings with total confidence.

I know there was another place てんとてん was used, and I think it was within a repeated phrase.  It went something like this:

> てんとてん　を　結ぶ ...

I'm trying to locate where this was said.  The next word might have been そうな and then something else, but I'm less sure about that part.

It's not in the Jim Breen dictionary, nor is any other similar pronunciation I can think of.  I also don't see very much particularly on Google.  Still, I'm sure about this usage and I hope that a native speaker will see these sentences and know right away what it's saying.

Comment: There is a song by Utada Hikaru called Deep River where she sings 点と点を結ぶ二人　

Maybe that's where you heard it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

てんとてん is not one word.

It is `[点]{てん}と[点]{てん}は[線]{せん}になる`, or, "two points make a line", or even "dots form/make a line".

`[点]{てん}と[点]{てん}を[結]{むす}ぶ` means "to connect two points", or even "connect the dots".

---

**UPDATE 1**

I think you are just hearing `せんになる` as `せぃになる`, because `んに` isn't always enunciated when people are speaking (kind of like American English "wanted to" is "wanitoo", or British English "isn't it" is "innit").  If you could provide the times at which the phrases appear in Ergo Proxy ep.1, then context can also be used for reference.

---

**UPDATE 2**

Okay, so she lists some events, then says:

> どれもが[化物]{ばけもの}につながり、[点]{てん}と[点]{てん}は[線]{せん}になる

Putting it in context, it kind of means:

> All of these events together lead back to the monster.

Comment: That's probably it.  I listed again to see if I could determine せん versus せい, and it could be either.  It goes by too fast and I can't tell.

Comment: I edited my answer.  Can you provide times for the lines?

Comment: For this episode 1 example, the line is after the credits.  In the version I have it's within 10 seconds before the absolute end.  The main character says it several times, but in this particular instance it's a short dialogue setting up the next episode.

Comment: Okay.  Answer updated again :)